# Determinant of anti-diagonal permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a $5\times5$ matrix $P=(5,4,3,2,1)$ which means it has anti-diagonal entries of $1$'s.

If we calculate $\det P$ using the theorem "The determinants changes sign when two rows are exchange", then it is : $$1  (making it identity)
But if we use cofactors then the answer is : $-1$
Is that possible? Which one is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that is not possible. You made an error using cofactors, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \det P &= \det\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
                                0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
                                0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
                                0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                                1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\
         &= (-1)^{1+5} \det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
                                0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
                                0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
                                1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\
         &= 1 \cdot (-1)^{1+4} \det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\
                                0 & 1 & 0\\
                                1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\
         &= -1 \cdot (-1)^{1+3} \det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\
                                1 &0\end{pmatrix}\\
         &= -1 \cdot (-1)\\
          &= 1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The (1,5)-th minor $M_{15}$ of $P$ (i.e. the determinant of the 4x4 submatrix obtained by removing the first row and the fifth column of $P$) is $1$, so the (1,5)-th cofactor is $C_{15}=(-1)^{1+5}M_{15}=1$ and in turn, if you evaluate $\det P$ using cofactors, you should get the answer as $1$ too, not $-1$.